# Why was Frodo able to go to the Blessed Realm?

Tags: tolkiens-legendarium, the-lord-of-the-rings, the-return-of-the-king

All along, I had the impression that, as reward for resisting the One Ring and contributing towards the journey to its ultimate demise, Bilbo (for finally abandoning it), Frodo (for having done the most to carry the burden for the actual journey) and Sam (for carrying it when Frodo couldn't and successfully resisting temptation to take over as the main bearer) were granted passage to spend the remainder of their mortal days in the Undying Lands, where the Blessed Realm can help heal/protect their souls from the dark taint of the Ring until the end of their days.

I just found Arwen's wiki article, though, and a passage quotes thus:

> After marrying Aragorn, she bestowed upon Frodo Baggins a gift: Her place on the ships to Valinor.

This implies that Frodo was originally ineligible for entry into the Undying Lands, until Arwen gave him her ticket.

Is my prior impression wrong? I think it came from many years ago, the one time I read RotK. If I am correct, then why does the quoted passage seem to conflict it? Did I misinterpret it, or is it a movie vs book thing? If I am wrong and the quoted passage is correct, then:

- Why can Bilbo and Sam go to the Undying Lands? Whose place on the ships did they take?
- Arwen already gave up her immortality to be with Aragorn. She is known to have told her father Elrond: "There is now no ship that would bear me hence". I don't think the choice of abandoning immortality can be walked back once made, so why did she have a seat to offer to anyone by that point?
- Even if she still held a place on the ships to the West, is it her place to offer it to anyone?

Comment: I've moved my answer to the question @WadCheber linked to